# In wso2 identity server how to authenticate using fixed application token

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Basically What I am trying to create is a application will be registered as service provider which has scope(using OIDC dialect) defined in wso2 identity server. So, when user gets access token he will first invoke wso2 API manager which is integrated with wso2 identity server and wso2 API manager will do the assertion once it gets access token by passing to identity server. After the assertion happens in API manager, API manager will pass the access token to the end web-service. The end web-service will use the wso2 identity server `OAuth2 SOAP API` for assertion of access token along with claims which should be returned. If the token is active then based on the response claim returned by SOAP API end/target web-service will authenticate and allow/deny for the access.

Currently I am getting the access token by  implementing custom grant type which sets the access token for indefinite time. While generating access token I am passing `username`,`client key`,`client secret` based on these parameters I am generating access token.

But now I wanted to create a scope which has set of claims(using OIDC dialect) which is mapped to service provider in identity server and also user will be created based on these claims. So, after generating the token which I have done using custom grant type against user, if the user passes the access token for authentication I need to do the custom assertion/validation of token using the claims of user in wso2 identity server.

So, how can I associate scope with service provider/Oauth2 flow. And also how can I do the validation of token along with claims.

Comment: We are supporting OAuth2 standard grant types in WSO2 Identity Server. If you want this requirement you have two ways. First one is to extend the expiry time of the token but that is not recommended. Also you can write a custom OAuth2 grant type. You can find the reference from here. https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/writing-a-custom-oauth-2.0-grant-type/

Comment: @ShanChathusandaJayathilaka can we use jwt for this purpose

Comment: Are you asking whether you can use JWT token for the ID token?

Comment: yes any example with custom attributes for authentication with jwt?

Comment: If the custom attributes are claims, this will help you. https://medium.com/identity-beyond-borders/handling-custom-claims-with-openid-connect-in-wso2-identity-server-56d3b6e4319b

Comment: @ShanChathusandaJayathilaka thanks for the help!! custom grant type is now working, but how can I modify the OAuth2 assertion code for custom implementation.

Comment: Could you please provide more details for the requirement?

Comment: @ShanChathusandaJayathilaka I have updated my requirements in the question now , basically I wanted to know how can I validated the access token by custom implementation in identity server and also how to map scope with service provider.